# Recorrer tabla excel específica VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bucles

hoy traigo una pregunta un poco compleja y voy a intentar explicarla de la mejor manera posible para que los interesados en ayudarme entiendan todo perfectamente.

Quiero realizar una macro en excel con VBA que realice un trabajo manual y repetitivo en el que hay que revisar unas hojas de excel e introducir los datos en otra Hoja principal.

*(EL EJEMPLO DE ACONTINUACIÓN ESTA REALIZADO ÚNICAMENTE PARA STACKOVERFLOW, Y ESTÁ TODO EN LA MISMA HOJA PERO EN EL PROGRAMA REAL HAY MAS HOJAS)*

Para situaros, la tabla principal en la que tengo que introducir los datos resumidos es esta:
[image: Tabla principal]
Como veis hay un PRODUCT1, esto es un producto, en teoría cada producto utiliza una hoja diferente con los datos que luego ponemos en esta. Todas las hojas con sus respectivos Productos siguen el mismo patrón que es el que os pongo a continuación.
[image: Tabla producto]

Como podéis ver en las imágenes, tengo que insertar los datos de cada producto (Segunda tabla) en la Hoja principal (Primera tabla). Cada producto tiene diferentes Actions, estas acciones tienen unas acciones predecesoras (que se tienen que ejecutar antes que esta) y unas sucesoras (que se ejecutarán después de esta), estas pueden ser interiores (I.P) o exteriores como se puede ver.

Se sabe cual es la acción predecesora de cada acción porque es una exterior con un nombre muy largo o porque en el apartado I.P aparece el numero de la Work Station de la acción que le precede.

**VALE AHORA DESPUÉS DE ESTE ROLLO VIENE MI PREGUNTA**
Estoy teniendo problemas para realizar el bucle de manera que si yo estoy leyendo la ACTION3 y quiero escribir, su predecesor lo busque en las WorkStations y una vez lo ha encontrado lo escriba en predecesores de la forma como el ejemplo.

Comment: Puedes añadir tu código, ¿Que tienes hasta ahora? ¿En que parte tienes el error? . Te recomiendo que te pases por [ask] para ver como preguntar en el sitio.

Comment: De momento de código solo tengo un loop que lo que hace es recorrer en la tabla Productos los ACTIONS hasta que la fila es "Date:31/05/2018" que es cuando ya no hay mas ACTIONS, por eso no he peusto ningún código, y mi pregunta es de que manera puedo realizar un bucle para leer la tabla PRODUCTOS y poder escribir los datos en la principal de la manera que hay en el ejemplo.

Comment: Realmente mas que una macro yo pensaría en PowerQuery y joins para relacionar las tablas. Una macro puede ser muy compleja para algo que puede ser resuelto con técnicas de bases de datos relacionales...

Comment: Miraré información sobre el PowerQuery y lo que me comentas, gracias por la ayuda. @virtualdvid